# Pandas Add Values in Interval By Specific Increment

Tags: pandas

Is there a way using pandas functions to add values/rows by a particular increment?

For example:
This is what I have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1.1,2,2.8])
df
      value other1  other2 
zebra  0.3           250
bunny  0.7           10
rat    1.0           35
cat    1.1   100
dog    2.0   150
mouse  2.8   125
```

**EDIT 1:**

This is what I want, **where ideally the inserted rows' index are whatever is easiest but the previous row names are preserved.**

```
df_goal = pd.DataFrame([1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,2,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7,2.8])
df_goal
      value  other1   other2
zebra  0.3             250
1      0.4
2      0.5
3      0.6
bunny  0.7             10
5      0.8
6      0.9
rat    1.0             35
cat    1.1    100
1      1.2
2      1.3
3      1.4
4      1.5
5      1.6
6      1.7
7      1.8
8      1.9
dog    2.0   150
10     2.1
11     2.2
12     2.3
13     2.4
14     2.5
15     2.6
16     2.7
mouse  2.8   125
```

**EDIT 2:**

Also I would like to keep the values of `other` columns that were there previously and any new rows are simply empty or zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by [`numpy.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

```
#create index by value column
df = df.reset_index().set_index('value')

#reindex floatindex
s = 0.1
a = np.arange(df.index.min(),df.index.max() + s, step=s)
df = df.reindex(a, tolerance=s/2., method='nearest')

#replace NaN in another columns as index
cols = df.columns.difference(['index'])
df[cols] = df[cols].fillna('')

#replace NaN by range
s = pd.Series(np.arange(len(df.index)), index=df.index)
df['index'] = df['index'].combine_first(s)

#swap column with index
df = df.reset_index().set_index('index')
```

---

```
print (df)

       value other1 other2
index                     
zebra    0.3           250
1        0.4              
2        0.5              
3        0.6              
bunny    0.7            10
5        0.8              
6        0.9              
rat      1.0            35
cat      1.1    100       
9        1.2              
10       1.3              
11       1.4              
12       1.5              
13       1.6              
14       1.7              
15       1.8              
16       1.9              
dog      2.0    150       
18       2.1              
19       2.2              
20       2.3              
21       2.4              
22       2.5              
23       2.6              
24       2.7              
mouse    2.8    125
```

Comment: this works for the most part but I lose my index names that existed beforehand I would like to preserve them, I updated my question with this fact to be more clear.

Comment: Also, just noticed, the resulting dataframe made all other columns in my dataframe NaNs

Comment: Now it is more complicated. Give me some time.

Comment: Please check edited answer, I add one more column. After reindex you get `NaN`s, I replace them by `ffill`. Is is OK? Or then is possible replace by scalar like `df = df.reindex(a, tolerance=0.05, method='nearest', fill_value=0).reset_index().set_index('index')`

Comment: Sorry I didn't get a chance to review this until now. Your solution is really close to what I want I don't want to repeat the other columns like you did using `ffill`. I edited my question again for expected output.

Comment: Ok, there is only one column? Or more columns?

Comment: There are 2 to be exact.

Comment: like in your sample? Or one more and index?

Comment: Now the edits are exactly my sample dataset. The index is labels, I have one column that I want the interval spacing, and the others should simply retain their previous and fill the new empty spaces with either zero or NaN or empty. Thanks again

Comment: Hmmm, so there are multiple ranges? and if consecutive values need restart range from 0?

Comment: Multiple ranges? No, there is just one range, the `value` column goes from [0.3, 2.8] at 0.1 increments.

Comment: I think in final index.

Comment: Yes totally, could be from anything to anything by a set increment.